# Is it possible to camera-track 360 video?

Tags: tracking, panoramic

I have to deal with some equirectangular 360 footage. I need to use camera tracking to be able to stabilize it.

It seems like it isn't possible right out of the box, as I can't select a panorama camera in the presets. How can I use camera tracking on 360 footage?

My guess is that solving a panorama track should even be easier than solving a regular camera where you have to guess or approximate the fov.

Comment: Perhaps wrap the image onto the world and export a frame from the regular camera. Then use BLAM addon to decide orientation etc from the still?

Comment: I really need it for animation and not just a still frame. I probably could do as you say and just track the "front-view"-camera, but that would involve too many steps. PfTrack, Syntheyes, and CaraVR for Nuke seem to do what I need, but I'm still checking the options. This would be my ultimate goal right now: http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2990000/2982405/a195-kopf.pdf?ip=81.94.78.99&id=2982405&acc=OPEN&key=4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E6D218144511F3437&CFID=875108642&CFTOKEN=41825836&__acm__=1481641485_f40a10c539919821af393c781323cb90